# Passing string literals to stored procedure in android studio with EditText?

Tags: java, android, sql, user-interface

Second post here, the first one was extremely helpful so thank you for those that contributed. I will try to be concise with the issue I'm having. I am using android studio in intellij to develop an application. Part of the functionality of the app is a fragment that accepts a new username input from the end user, and then stores that username into my database (a preexisting database that has been linked to intellij). I am new to java and only in the last couple days started to change from creating UI with swing and awt, to xml files. My understanding is that xml files are data descriptors and useful for creating static objects/widgets while the .java files use java to create behaviors for the objects by referencing their IDs created in the xml file. Now comes the confusing part for me, and forgive me if this seems like a no brainer, as I'm pretty new to all this- I have "piggybacked" off a base shell for a android app, and as best as I can tell, setOnClickListener is essentially the android java version of action listeners. I added to the method that essentially took a button and navigated from one fragment to the next, with code that connects to the database, and then executes the stored procedure presumably when the "next"/"submit" button is clicked. Now here's the catch: obviously when a submit button is clicked, there is no user defined username that gets passed into the stored procedure, so obviously it won't work. The problem is, the TextEdit text field that I created is created in an xml file with no way to reference it or manipulate it in the java code, yet it accepts "text" parameters and works fine in the emulator. Obviously I want the stored procedure to take the user inputs in that text field and store it as a new username in the database, but since xml just describes data, and there isn't any defined text field in the java code, I'm at a loss for how to accomplish this task. I can't just write up an action listener and attach it to the xml id of the TextEdit because there isn't anything in the xml file that explains where the actual typed characters are! I know, higher level programming issues. Can anyone help explain how to do what I'm trying to do? Preferably as much as possible in laymans terms. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.callit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.sql.*;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
                String sqldatabase = "//database connection url";
                try {
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(sqldatabase);
                    CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{EXEC    [dbo].[CreateUser] @UserName = N'Dog', @UserID = @UserID OUTPUT}");
                    cs.execute();

                } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                    throwables.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
    }
}
```

I included it in case there was something inherently wrong with the connection to the database code (I also am aware that I should disconnect from the database as well). I would like to note that the code runs without errors, it just doesn't do what it should (for the reasons I explained above). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you sure you want to let a user run SQL queries on your database? I mean, connecting the DB to your app is 99% of the times a bad thing

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. It would initiate a connection but also drop it after the procedure runs. The user isn't going to be running any queries on the database. I mentioned above that I understood the disconnect command was not included in my example code.

Comment: you know that you have to save the log in information for the connection in the APK, and so everybody can see the username and password of your database?

Comment: It uses windows credentials, not a username and password for the database. At any rate, none of that helps solve the initial problem I am having. Further research has confirmed to me that my primary question was me not trusting the intrinsic abilities of the system to handle certain base executions. My current issue is creating an onFocusChangeListener method that doesn't throw a million syntax errors with a number of them having unhelpful tooltips (cannot resolve symbol ###), even when the syntax used mimics tutorials or even the boiler plate code of android studio

Comment: Of course the reason for my confusion is that I don't understand the inner workings of a few things, which only compounds the rabbit trail of google tabs I have raging through my internet browser right now. Don't get me wrong, I'm learning at record pace, but I need to make progress on this app and learn at the same time, so its vital for me to have solutions to these problems even without me fully understanding what's going on.

Comment: If your (or anyones) response creates more questions than answers it isn't helpful at this juncture

Comment: mine is not an answer, infact it's on the **comment** section...

Comment: Yes I understand that. It was more for anyone who read the comment thread and wished to answer